# Export wizard gives error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Whenever I want to export from my plug-in xml, it gives the following error:

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this??

Comment: A screen shot of an error message? Are you serious? Please post the log as text.

Answer (score 2):

Check, if the file `D:\fastcode_new\plugins\org.fastcode_1.3.0\icons\sample.gif` exists and isn't write protected.

Comment: When I did for 1 st time, export wizard gave the same error though there is only empty folder fastcode_new.After that I saw within the fastcode_new->plugin folder there is sample.gif exist and I saw for user it is read only but in case of admistrator,it is read write ,execute everything

Answer (score 1):

It tries to delete the file samlpe.gif (in D:\fastcode_new\plugins\org.fastcod_1.3.0\icons directory).  If the file is open in another program that can cause this problem.

Sometimes you might not think it is held open, but if you did open it in a program before and upon closing the .gif program did not release it properly, it still counts a being held open.  In this situation the only thing you can do is close all programs thay you ever used to open the file previously.